# Brocade configuration backup Error: configUpload: failed to get tty info

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

Need help. I am using Python 3.4.3 and trying to prepare a simple script for Brocade configuration upload. For now, trying the configupload command on one Brocade IP but FTP fails with below error (while any other command like 'version', 'switchname' etc works just fine)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FTP command used in script: configupload -all -ftp ,ftpuser,ftppassword,cfgfilename.txt
Error: configUpload: failed to get tty info

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FTP Server: Windows using Filezilla server interface

When I run the exact command inside the switch after loggin in, it works fine.
I am using:
import paramiko
paramiko.SSHClient()

Please let me know if anything else is needed (like the entire script).

Thanks

Comment: What has FileZilla **FTP** server to do with executing an **SSH/shell** command using Paramiko?

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: @Martin.....awesome man!